# Mikrotik JS JSON to Array object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
[
    {
      "field": ".id",
      "value": "*0"
    },
    {
      "field": "name",
      "value": "default-trial"
    },
    {
      "field": "uptime",
      "value": "0s"
    },
    {
      "field": "comment",
      "value": "counters and limits for trial users"
    }
  ],
```

Which one is the fastest way to convert it into an object? I would like to have an object like this

User {
  id : 0,
  name: default-trial,
  ...
}

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what do you want to do... You have an array with 4 objects, and want to convert it to a single object?

Comment: He wants to turn the field of the object into a key for the new one, and the value into the value

Comment: Yes i edit the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
'use strict';

const arr = [
    {
      "field": ".id",
      "value": "*0"
    },
    {
      "field": "name",
      "value": "default-trial"
    },
    {
      "field": "uptime",
      "value": "0s"
    },
    {
      "field": "comment",
      "value": "counters and limits for trial users"
    }
];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, { field, value }) => {
  acc[field] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const array = [
    {
        field: '.id',
        value: '*0'
    },
    {
        field: 'name',
        value: 'default-trial'
    },
    {
        field: 'uptime',
        value: '0s'
    },
    {
        field: 'comment',
        value: 'counters and limits for trial users'
    }
]

const result = array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current.field] = current.value

    return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build objects and assign all to a single object.

```js
var data = [{ field: ".id", value: "*0" }, { field: "name", value: "default-trial" }, { field: "uptime", value: "0s" }, { field: "comment", value: "counters and limits for trial users" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({ field, value }) => ({ [field]: value })));

console.log(object);
```